# How can I catch a browser timeout and execute my own error message?

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic, timeout

I have a web page (classic asp) with a link to a local IP address, as follows:

```
<a href="http://192.168.1.89">Link</a>
```

If the local IP address is unavailable the web browser eventually times out and displays its own error message.

What I want to do is: catch the timeout before the browser displays its default error page and display an error on the same web page, next to the "Link".

e.g. `<a href="http://192.168.1.89">Well Pump</a><div id="timeoutmsg">offline</div>`

I am guessing I need some JavaScript and the timeout function, but I don't know where to begin.

Comment: are these dynamic urls or hardcoded? I think the only way to do this is to iterate over each with something like ajax and see if you get 200

Comment: you can't ... clicking a link `<a>` navigates away from the current page

Comment: The URLs are hard coded.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a link per-say. I was thinking of changing that to a button.

Comment: You can do it .. but it requires javascript.  I have a program I'm building that has a built in session timer and one per user as well as a separate timer that ever 30 mins or an hour depending, pops up and gives them 2 minutes to put in the pin, before it punts them out of the online table and thus logs them out.  Short answer - can't do it with asp classic, long answer- can do it with javascript on top of asp classic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this awesome workaround using pure javascript, no JScript, no ajax, no external libraries.
Works at treat:
Just need to upload a "test.gif" file to the local site(s).

```
var url = 'http://192.168.1.89';
var img = new Image();
img.src = url + '/test.gif';
img.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "";
    window.location.href = url;
}
img.onerror = function() {
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "offline";
}
```